# Nestjs: Use TypeOrm datasource without class dependency injection

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I have an unusual request.
We are implementing nestjs into our existing express codebase. Before, we were using Typeorm 0.2 and upgraded to 0.3. We are using **functions and not classes, therefore, without huge refactoring, we can't use datasource dependency injection.** The goal is to use the datasource without the nestjs dependecy injection.

We used to build transactions this way:

```js
import { getManager } from 'typeorm';
    
return getManager().transaction((manager) => {
  // do something
});
```

Now, with TypeOrm 0.3, `getManager` is deprecated. The code is compiling and all requests that don't contain the `getManager` function are working. When the function containing it is called, I get the following error:

```
ConnectionNotFoundError: Connection "default" was not found.
```

I tried to work with the datasource directly, but the infamous error of "metadata not found" is coming up and the code does not even compile.

```
import { getManager } from 'typeorm';

return AppDataSource.transaction((manager) => {
  // do something
});
```

```
Entity metadata for BuyerIndustry#companies was not found. Check if you specified a correct entity object and if it's connected in the connection options.
```

This is, how we set up the datasource and imported it in the `AppModule`:

```js
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';
import { repositories } from './repositories';

const configService = new ConfigService();

export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
    type: 'postgres',
    host: configService.get('POSTGRES_HOST'),
    port: configService.get('POSTGRES_PORT'),
    username: configService.get('POSTGRES_USER'),
    password: configService.get('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
    database: configService.get('POSTGRES_DB'),
    migrations: [__dirname + '/src/database/migrations/*{.ts,.js}'],
    entities: repositories,
    synchronize: false,
});
```

```
// repositories.ts
export const repositories = [
    BuyerIndustry,
    Company,
    // and all other entities in the application
];
```

```
// typeorm.module.ts
import { Global, Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { DataSource } from 'typeorm';
import { AppDataSource } from './datasource';

@Global()
@Module({
    imports: [],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: DataSource,
            useFactory: async () => {
                await AppDataSource.initialize();

                return AppDataSource;
            },
        },
    ],
    exports: [DataSource],
})
export class CustomTypeOrmModule {}
```

```
// main.module.ts

@Module({
    imports: [
        CustomTypeOrmModule,
        // other modules
    ]
export class AppModule {
    constructor(private dataSource: DataSource) {}
}
```

Again, I am 100% certain that I imported ALL entities in the `repositories.ts`. Any idea, how we can use the `DataSource` directly in functions, without needing a class with the datasource injected?
Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First make sure AppDataSource is initialized. you can do this in the `main.ts` file

```
// main.ts
import {AppDataSource } from "..." // Your datasource file

 if (!AppDataSource.isInitialized) {
    await AppDataSource.initialize();
  }
```

then call it in any service like so

```
const someRepo = AppDataSource.getRepository(SomeRepoEntity);

someRepo.findOne({where:{id:someId}})
```